# Speed of trajectory is constant, but not with any parametrization?

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, parametric, parametrization

Let $m$ be a constant.

Say I have a particle moving with constant speed $u$ along the curve in $x-y$ plane given in polar coordinates by $r=e^{m\theta}$, where $r$ is the radius. I think I can parametrize this as:
$$f(t)=e^{mt}(\cos(t),\sin(t)),$$
it starts at $t=0$ and hence at radius $r=1$.

- I want to find the particles distance from the origin at time $t$.

So I find the velocity by deriving $f(t):$
$$\dot{f}(t)=(me^{mt}\cos(t)-e^{mt}\sin(t),me^{mt}\sin(t)+\cos(t)),$$
and so if I take the euclidean norm, to find the speed, I have:
$$\|\dot{f}(t)\|=e^{mt}(1+m^2),$$
where we have that $u$ is the constant velocity, so:
$$e^{mt}(1+m^2)=u,$$
this disturbs me, since as $t$ increases, where $m$ is constant, the LHS increases, yet the RHS i.e. speed is constant, so this cannot be possible?

Then I suppose I have to reparametrize my path with some function of $h(t)$ in place of $t$, so as to ensure it is moving at the correct speed?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @FaraadArmwood How to parametrize $g(\theta)=e^{m\theta}$, so that it moves at speed $u$. So I can determine the radius at time $t$?

Comment: The radius of what? Your function is $g(t) = e^{mt}$ where $m \in \mathbb{R}$. The graph of this function is an exponential curve.

Comment: @FaraadArmwood Sorry, I should have made that clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curve $f(t) = e^{mt} [\cos(t), \sin(t)]$ does indeed have nonconstant speed
$e^{mt} \sqrt{m^2+1}$.  In order to make the speed constant, you could take $t = T(s)$ where
$$\dfrac{dT}{ds} = e^{-mT}$$   The solutions to this differential equation are 
$$ T(s) = \frac{1}{m} \ln(a + m s) $$
for arbitrary constant $a$.  Thus you could parametrize your curve as
$$ F(s) = (a + m s) \left[\cos\left(\frac{\ln(a+ms)}{m}\right), \; \sin\left(\frac{\ln(a+ms)}{m}\right)\right] $$